Using an Active Inrush Current Limiter as an Alternative to a Pre-Charge Circuit in EVs
I'm currently working on a master's thesis during an internship at an automotive company that manufactures EVs. The thesis focuses on improving a pre-charge circuit for an EV. In EVs, a pre-charge circuit is a circuit used to slowly charge the capacitor within the motor's inverter to the battery's level in order to limit the inrush current. Traditionally, this is done using a relay/resistor combination. The battery is isolated from the rest of the system with two contactors, one on the positive rail and the other on the negative rail of the battery. Initially, the negative contactor closes, followed by the relay. Once closed, the relay provides a resistive path to the inverter's capacitor to limit the current flowing through it, thereby slowing the charging rate of the capacitor according to the time constant \$\tau=R\cdot C\$. Once the capacitor reaches to battery's level, the positive main contactor closes, and the relay opens, allowing full current to flow through the inverter.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This circuit works as intended, but that doesn't mean it doesn't have its shortcomings. One of the major problem of this circuit is having an electromechanical relay. Because of its mechanical nature, it is prone to wear and tear. To address this, I though of basing my solution on something that doesn't rely on components having moving parts. Since the goal here is to limit the inrush current, I thought to myself, why not using a proper inrush current limiter to do the same job as the pre-charge circuit. Through some research, I stumbled across this article that discusses an active inrush current limiter circuit (AICL for short) based on a MOSFET. After reading the article multiple times, I found the information along with the design relatively simple to grasp ( bear in mind that I'm not an electrical engineer, so I might be lacking on certain areas when it comes to electrical engineering) , plus the solution is based on semi-conductors, so no moving part for me. Since this approach ticks all my boxes, I decided to go with it.
From  what I understood, this design exploits the switching characteristics of the MOSFET to control the rate of change of the drain-source voltage, thereby controlling the drain current.
Here is the circuit mentioned in the article:

Here \$C_{filter}\$ is the capacitor that we want to pre-charge. So by putting this capacitor between the positive side of the battery and the drain of the MOSFET, we can effectively limit the inrush current running through the capacitor.
The article lists design equations so we can customize the circuit to our needs. The following equation is all I needed to put together my own implementation:
$$dt = C_{\text{filter}} \cdot \frac{V_{DD}}{I_{\text{inrush}}}$$
$$V_{plt} = V_{th} + \frac{I_{\text{load}}}{g_{fm(\text{max})}}$$
$$I_{gd} \approx C_{gd'} \cdot \frac{dV_{DS}}{dt}$$
$$R_G = \frac{(V_{GG} - V_{GS})}{I_{gd}}$$
$$
V_{ch}=V_{th_{min}}-V_{DG}
$$
$$
 C_{ch}=\frac{C_{gd}^{'}\cdot (V_{DD}-V_{ch})}{V_{ch}}
$$
$$t_{delay}=5.3R_{GD}C_{gd}^{'}$$
$$ R_{ch} \geq \frac{1}{C_{ch}}\cdot \frac{t_{delay}}{\left|ln\left| 1- \frac{V_{plt}-V_{ch}-V_{DG}}{V_{DD}}\right | \right |}$$
Here are the values for my specific application:



\$V_{bat}\$
\$450V\$




\$C_{inv}\$
\$1.7mF\$


\$I_{inrush}\$
\$15A\$


\$V_{th}\$
\$4.5V\$


\$V_{GG}\$
\$12V\$


\$g_{fm_{max}}\$
\$14S\$


\$C_{gs}^{'}\$
\$0.1\mu F\$


\$R_{GD}\$
\$100\Omega\$


\$V_{DG}\$
\$0.7V\$



I plugged these values into the equations, and I got the following results:
$$ R_{G}=7286\Omega$$
$$ C_{ch}=11.7\mu F$$
$$ R_{ch}\geq 1893.48\Omega$$
Bear in mind that these values are supposed to limit the inrush current to \$15A\$.
To test the validity of these equations, I put together a software simulation in LTspice.

After running the simulation, I was surprised to find that the inrush current was above 450A, far exceeding my expectations. I'm genuinely confused and unsure where the problem originates and how to approach it. I thought that by following the design steps outlined in the article, I would achieve the desired result, but unfortunately, that didn't happen.

I haven't completely lost hope in this approach because I'm certain there's an important element I'm overlooking. My last resort is to seek help from experts in the field, and there's no better place than this awesome community. If anyone has any ideas about this or is already working in this field, please don't hesitate to help me. I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much for taking the time to read all of this.

Here is a table that lists all major components used in the simulation:



MOSFET
R6020PNJ




Diode
1N5408


Zener diode
PDZVTR12B




what's the plan with this circuit, to use the NMOS to control the current? How is it supposed to do that? Are you using some sort of Miller multiplier for cdg? If you turn it on, current flows through its RDSon. If you don't turn it on, it will get very hot very fast at 15 A, if you could control its current to 15 A. Why not use a buck converter configuration?

From what I understood, this circuit is supposed to control the drain current  by controlling the rate of change of the drain-source voltage. This can be achieved by adding an external capacitor $C_{gd}^{'}$ parallel to  $C_{gd}$. By adding this capacitor, we can extend the miller region, allowing us to control the rate at which Vds decreases when the NMOS tunrs on. By doing that, we can in theory limit the inrush current initially pulled by the capacitor.

OK, so run through some numerical calculations. What dv/dt do you get for 15 A into Cinv? What will be the charge current for Cgd at this dv/dt? What charge current are you expecting with the gate bias components you have chosen? How about plotting more things in your simulation than just ICinv? You still need \ $ in comments for mathjax to work on this site, as well as in your question.

Practically, this circuit is going to be hard to get working properly. Assuming you get your unorthodox soft-start circuit working as designed, that MOSFET is going to have to  carry the working current which is many times higher than the inrush limit. This is why the original designers opted for a real relay instead of a solid-state solution. Plus, that relay is barely switching. After you get the vehicle started it's not like it's constantly toggling all the way down the road to the destination.


One of the major problem of this circuit is having an electromechanical relay.

It's not a major problem. If it were, precharge relays would not be used in millions of Electric Vehicles. The current in the precharge relay is low and there is no inrush nor kickback current. As far as relay applications go, this is one of the most benign.

To address this, I though of basing my solution on something that doesn't rely on components having moving parts.

In so doing, you introduced what actually is a major problem: you have broken the galvanic isolation between the string of cells and the rest of the vehicle. In traction batteries with a voltage higher than 48 V, for safety and to meet regulatory requirements, when the battery is off there must be no connection between the cells and the battery terminals. Your active precharge circuit defeats that because a solid state component (MOSFET M1 in your case) is not an open circuit even when it's "off".
In short, you have come up with "a solution in search of a problem". And you introduced a bigger problem.

Setting all that aside for a moment, let's look at your circuit.
You are replacing a precharge relay that is carefully controlled by algorithms in the ECU software with a MOSFET that is controlled by RC time constants. Doing so introduces more problems because the RC time constant doesn't address issues that are solved by the ECU software. For example, say that the driver turns on the ignition, 0.3 s later turns it back off, and 0.3 s later turns it back on. Your circuit will not complete the precharge because the capacitors will not be fully discharged during the short time the ignition is off. But the software algorithm knows how to deal with this situation, and will ensure that the precharge is completed.
So, again, your solution introduced additional problems.

Your math is sound, yes, but you need to look at the forest before you look at the trees.
